# plot multiple graphs within for loop in r

Tags: r

I am trying to plot within a for loop in r, which is a very simple task in python. I would like 3 plots based on a parameter taking 3 different values.

my code

```
clust <- list(3,4,5)

for (i in clust)

set.seed(42)
k_clust = kmeans(
  college_scaled,
  centers = i,
  nstart = 25
  )

fviz_cluster(
  k_clust,
  data = college_scaled,
  main = "Colleges Segmented by Average Faculty Salary and Tuition Rates",
  geom= c("point","text"),
  labelsize= 8,
  pointsize= 1,
  ggtheme= theme_minimal()
)
```

For some reason this only plots `centers = 5` instead of iterating through the loop and plotting 3,4, and 5. Why is this?

Comment: Where are the curly braces enclosing the body of the for-loop?

Comment: I tried that and nothing plotted. Without them, only one plot is generated @cdalitz

Comment: Save the result in the list.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have `college_scaled` data to replicate your code, for block doesn't include both `k_clust` and `fviz_cluster` commands. Add `{`, `}` to keep both in the loop:

```
clust <- list(3,4,5)

for (i in clust)
{  
  set.seed(42)
k_clust = kmeans(
  college_scaled,
  centers = i,
  nstart = 25
)

print(
  fviz_cluster(
    k_clust,
    data = college_scaled,
    main = "Colleges Segmented by Average Faculty Salary and Tuition Rates",
    geom= c("point","text"),
    labelsize= 8,
    pointsize= 1,
    ggtheme= theme_minimal()
  )
)
}
```

Edit: added print based [starja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12647315/starja) on reminder in comments.